# How to make a HTTP post request like a HTML form using Axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

I am trying to connect to an API ([nova.astrometry.net](https://nova.astrometry.net)) that requires an HTTP post request just like a form (x-www-form-encoded). I am using Axios for that, but still, I am getting this error as a response from the API `{ status: 'error', errormessage: 'no json' }`

Here's the code for reference

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://nova.astrometry.net/api/login',
    data: {
        'request-json': JSON.stringify({ "apikey": process.env.API_KEY })
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data)
});
```

I also tried using the request library but got the same response.

Answer (score 0):

The content type required by the api is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` but you are sending `'application/json'`.

To send that data, do the following:

```js
const body = new URLSearchParams();
body.append('request-json', JSON.stringify({ "apikey": process.env.API_KEY }));
```

Then use the above body in the body field of axios.

```js
axios.post('http://nova.astrometry.net/api/login', body, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
})
  .then(res => console.log(res.body))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: ```{ status: 'error', errormessage: 'need "apikey"' }``` getting this now.

Comment: This is probably because the api key is not available in process.env . Log it and see if it is defined.

Comment: process.env is enabled. I am using dotenv for that.